# How to find average color of area in an Image?

Tags: android, opencv

I have a `Mat` of detected `circles` using `HoughCircles` and I iterate through them and add them to a `List`
Now I want to get the average color of detected circles to check if that circle is marked or not (for example the image below)

[image]

```java
Mat circles = new Mat();
Imgproc.HoughCircles(adaptiveThresh, circles, Imgproc.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.0, (double) adaptiveThresh.rows() / 40, 100.0, 30.0, 20, 30);

List<Circle> circleList = new ArrayList<>();
Point p1 = new Point(0, 0);

for (int x = 0; x < circles.cols(); x++) {
    double[] c = circles.get(0, x);
    Point center = new Point(Math.round(c[0]), Math.round(c[1]));
    int radius = (int) Math.round(c[2]);
    Imgproc.circle(source, center, radius, new Scalar(255,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );

    Circle circle = new Circle();
    circle.centerY = (int) center.y;
    circle.centerY = (int) center.y;

    circle.radius= radius;

    circle.x = circle.centerX - circle.radius;
    circle.y = circle.centerY - circle.radius;

    circle.distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(p1.x - circle.centerX), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(p1.y - circle.centerY), 2));

    circleList.add(circle);
    Log.d(TAG, "scan2: x->" + circle.x + "\ty->" + circle.y);
}
```

Hopefully I get all 200 circles from this image but I want to detect which circles are marked (for example the first row and the second circle is marked!)

How can I detect which circle is marked and also know which row and column it is!

There are 2 columns that in each column is 25 rows that each row has 4 circles, overall there is 200 circles

Answer (score 0):

what you want is

```
static Scalar   mean(Mat src) 
          Calculates an average (mean) of array elements.
```

The circle detected, draw a closed circle as a mask, input

```
Mat maskimg=new Mat(); //this image changes for every different circle
Imgproc.circle(maskimg, center, radius, new Scalar(255,255,255), **-1**, 8, 0 );
//draw filled circle on a image
Scalar averagecolor=core.mean(inputimage,masking);
double averageintensity=(averagecolor[0]+averagecolor[1]
+averagecolor[2])/3

if(averageintensity> your preset)
check position to see if answer is correct based on the official answer position
```

My java is bad. I wrote it without compiling. So there could be grammar mistake use it with caution